# In the ubiquity installer, what does the 'skip' button do?

Tags: 18.04, ubiquity

I've always been terrified to click on this button by accident.  Especially when the screen goes black and I have to press a key.

But what does it do? Skip a page in the slide show, or the install step?  Or is it in fact, greyed out at this point? Is my fear unwarranted?

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, that button is only enabled while Ubuntu is downloading updates after the main installation has finished, but I might remember it incorrectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some apt configuration will be skipped.

If the 'skip' button was clicked, some verbose messages may be seen within the embedded terminal that is collapsible below the slideshow and nothing else; the installation will proceed and complete anyway.

The combined screenshots during installation as follows.

[image: The state of skip button during installation]

The button is disabled (greyed out) almost all the time, and will only be enabled when the installer is configuring apt during the installation. If the button is clicked early enough, user will not see such line of text "Retrieving files N of N".

This could be a bug: The button may not be shown unless the embedded terminal is collapsed. As of 16.04 release, the button is shown from the beginning, but the button will actually hide itself when the embedded terminal is collapsed and uncollapsed. User experience may vary from release to release.

**TL;DR** The button will skip something trivial, which does not affect the installation.